# AngularJS - ng-show not showing div tag conditionally?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to show a div tag on a form based on the boolean flag that is specified in ng-show. But the div is not displaying at all. Below is what I tried and it is not working. Thanks for any help!

Form control in MVC View:

```
<form name="payment" role="form" ng-submit="sendPayment()" ng-controller="PaymentCtrl">
        <div id="veil" ng-show="isProcessing == true"></div>
        <div id="feedLoading" ng-show="isProcessing == true">
            <img src="~/images/ajax_loader_blue_64.gif" class="img-responsive center-block" />
        </div>

        //Other form controls here
</form>
```

In Angular controller:
This controller is same as the one the form is using which is "PaymentCtrl".

```
$scope.isProcessing = false;

    $scope.setProcessing = function (loading) {
        $scope.isProcessing = loading;
    }

    $scope.sendPayment = function () {
        $scope.setProcessing(true);
        //Other logic here
        $scope.setProcessing(false);
    };
```

CSS Styles for div tags:

```
#veil {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
cursor: not-allowed;
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
opacity: 0.6;
background: #000000 url(http://www.wingo.com/angular/AngularShieldLogo.png) no-repeat center;
}

#feedLoading {
position: absolute;
top:200px;
width:100%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 4em;
color:white;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #021124;
}
```

Comment: What is that "other logic" part? Also - `ng-show="isProcessing"` is all you need - no need for that `== true`

Comment: Eventhough you are doing `//Other logic here` part, you are still setting it to false in the next statement synchronously with setting it to true some lines before. So it works as expected. DOM will not be updated just after you set it to true.

Comment: Sorry, but very unclear `//Other logic here`

Comment: It's actually relevant what's happening in `//other logic here`.  Is it an asynchronous service call?  Does it use a promise to handle a server response?  Please show that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sendPayment` is probably making an asynchronous service call which is waiting to be resolved via a promise.  Your `isProcessing` boolean is being toggled immediately back at the end of the function's execution.  No matter when your promise actually resolves, your boolean has already been changed.

You should instead reset your `isProcessing` boolean after your promise comes back.  Make sure to reset it in both the success and error callback functions.  For example, if your code is using a promise:

```
service.sendPayment() 
    .then(function() {
            $scope.setProcessing(false);
        },
        function(error) {
            $scope.setProcessing(false);
        });
```

Or if you are using `$http` in your controller, you can use the wrapped `.success` and `.error` callbacks:

```
$http.post(url, data) 
    .success(function () {
        $scope.setProcessing(false);
    })
    .error(function (error) {
        $scope.setProcessing(false);
    });
```

Comment: Instead of resetting it in success and failurs, it can be done in finally block. Also to mentio.n they both are deprecated instead should start using then and catch

Comment: Thank you. It is working now. The other logic part calls a web service which was executing too quickly which made it look like the div tag never displayed.